# Even, Odd, Congruent

Tags: notation, congruences

Im new in math world, i know the modulo congruence in order to defining odd and even. But I don't know if i can write

Even is $$x \equiv 2x$$
Odd is $$x \equiv 2x + 1$$

If it's not that, can you explain me why ?

Thank you

Comment: Odd is $x\equiv 1\pmod{2}$ or $x=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. Even is $x\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ or $x=2k$ for some integer $k$.  People in Computer Science use modulus a bit differently, and for odd might write $x\bmod 2=1$, for even might write $x\bmod 2=0$.

Comment: Note that your congruences are (with the addition of '$\pmod 2$') _correct_ - they're just not the usual way of writing things.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, i better understand the congruence.